# Keras Flatten Layer Input Shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am running the following Keras model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(6457,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

print("Shape of x: " + str(x.shape))
model.fit(x,y, epochs=5)
```

The shape of X is, as printed in runtime:

```
Shape of x: (6457,)
```

However, the error I am encountering is:

> expected flatten_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (6457, 1)

Comment: The `input_shape` refers to shape of only one sample (and not all of the training samples) which is `(1,)` in this case. However, it is strange that with this shape (i.e. `(1,)`) you are using a Flatten layer since It is already flattened.

Comment: I had a problem with the resize. Now I'm resizing properly to (64, 64), Receiving this error: expected flatten_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6457, 64, 64)

Answer (score 2):

I was improperly resizing the image. I thought the CV2 functions work in place but instead had to have them return into the variable I was passing on, like so:

```
im1 = cv2.resize(image, (64,64))
im2 = cv2.blur(im1,(5,5))
return im2
```

After this it was simply a matter of supplying the image size (64,64) to the Flatten layer:

```
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(64,64))
```